# Visual Studio ArcGIS App Project Subtype error during creation

Tags: xamarin.ios, arcgis, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to create an Application template in Visual Studio for ArcGIS but it keeps showing the same error the subtype hasn't been recorded anywhere, i tried repairing visual studio and tried to download Developer Insight tools too.. but it didn't work it had another error..
The error for the template is as follows:
[Template Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcu3p.png)

The Error for installing Developer Analytics tools is as follows:
[Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSimP.jpg)

The log for the installation error is as follows:
*VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData) at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)*

Answer (score 0):

So i got a workaround for the solution and it is quite simple.

Basically you need to

1. Uninstall the visual studio 2022
2. Install it back
3. Before installing, you get a window asking what all types of softwares need to be installed
4. Search for Xamarin, you get a 7 GB file once you select it, after installing visual studio it works.